# zip a file with maven to a NO java application directory

Tags: node.js, maven, jenkins, vue.js, artifactory

I don´t know if this is possible . This is what I want to do.
I have some jenkins pipelines that build a VUE.js application using node js.
using the "nmp run build" command. The result  of this build, is  the directory name "Static" and a index.html file. After that I zip those 2 into a file.zip which I upload to Artifactory, so later it can be downloaded unziped and put it into a docker file to build an image and later a container in azure (ACI).

I want to implement some versioning now of those zips which I already done with other apps but in Java with  maven + POM +  Maven+Metadata+Plugin + jenkins+ artifactory  where I have 2 jobs. 1 job to build with maven and push to artifactory the file.war, and other job to choose the file.war from artifactory with "build with parameters" option.

I read something about using also maven for creating a zip file even though is not a java app   [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) and do the same for node js.

So, Is it possible with maven to zip a directory and a file even thought they are not a java app and include job number to version this zip file and pushing into artifactory?, if not, which is the best approach to do the same as I did with Java and maven for versioning, but for VUE.js applications in a jenkins pipeline that push a zip along with build number into  artifactory and then using the "build with parameters" option to choose the zip I want?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, that you are already using npm to build your Vue app. There are libraries for npm available for zipping. You could e.g. do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');

const archive = archiver('zip', {
  zlib: { level: 9 }
});

const filename = "./output.zip";
const fileOutput = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

fileOutput.on('close', function() {
  console.info('ZIP file created. ' + archive.pointer() + ' total Bytes.');
});

archive.pipe(fileOutput);
archive.directory('./input-directory', '/');

archive.on('error', function(error) {
  throw error;
});

archive.finalize();
```

---

This assumes, that the output of your build process is stored in a `dist` folder on your file system and that you have access to the filesystem.

There are more examples of `archiver` in the official docs: https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver

Comment: yes but does this have any kind of integration with jenkins and artifactory for work with some versioning? same as maven?

Answer (score 0):

You may build a zip file using the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) with an assembly descriptor.

The assembly descriptor goes in the project's `src/assembly` directory, named something like `my-zip-format.xml`. You'll need to customize the content to include the files needed but this is the idea.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>my-zip</id>

    <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>path/to/input/dir</directory>
        <outputDirectory>name-of-output-dir</outputDirectory>
        <directoryMode>0750</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>0640</fileMode>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Then, tell the POM to use the assembly:

```
....
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version><pluginVersionHere></version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-zip</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/my-zip-format.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        ...
```

Documentation goes into a lot more detail, and there are plenty of SO questions/answers about assembly plugin nuances as well.

Comment: yes I read tha,t so basically I need to create and add in the directory that contain the static directoy  and the index.html a POM file and the  and the zip.xml I guess and ALL THAT put them into a directory named src/assembly ? Or the directory name is not important? just adding the pom and the zip.xml among Static folder and index.html?....